# vba := expected for a sub

Tags: excel, vba, procedure

I have a procedure :

```
Sub FormulaToNumber(sheetName As String, sheetRange As String)
Dim sh As Worksheet, Cell As Range, Plage As Range
Set sh = Worksheets(sheetName)

    sh.Select

    With sh

    Set Plage = .Range(sheetRange)

    For Each Cell In Plage
        Cell.Value = Format(Cell.Value, "Fixed")
    Next

    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

And I am trying to call my procedure like that :

```
FormulaToNumber("temps_ress", "D3:O95")
```

But Excel can't let me call my procedure, a messagebox appear with this text :
"Error := expected"
I think it wants a assination like : FormulaToNumber("temps_ress", "D3:O95") = variable, but why ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use either of two option:

```
Call FormulaToNumber("temps_ress", "D3:O95")
```

OR

```
FormulaToNumber "temps_ress", "D3:O95"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:=` operator is used for calling a function/procedure with *named arguments*... but I don't see anywhere where you're trying to do that. However...

> And I am trying to call my procedure like that :
>
> ```
> FormulaToNumber("temps_ress", "D3:O95")
> ```

Drop the parentheses:

```
FormulaToNumber "temps_ress", "D3:O95"
```